# Java ArrowKey Listener

Tags: java, events, logic, keylistener

So I have created this program in which I am trying to get something that moves a blue square according to the arrow keys. However, I have some problems (as you shall see in the code). I have searched all over the web for an answer, but to no prevail. 
Here are my problems:

- I want it to move and hold a position, whereas my code just resets it back to where it started. I fooled around with this but couldn't fix it.
- I want it to be able to move diagonal, and in any direction and not just one direction at a time, so the ability to change direction during a movement
- I want to be able to hold the keys down to move it, which doesn't seem a problem
- Along with the fluid motion described above, I am also trying to get it to not move in such a way that looks like a parabola (it increases too much when a key is held).

I may just have some logical problems, or there is a simpler way to get Java to do this. If so, please leave an explicit explanation. 
Please ignore the random notes I have jotted down all over the place.

```
//graham

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Arrows extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
private int c = 0, c1 = 0;
private int x = 250;
private int y = 250;
private int cx = 0; //change in x
private int cy = 0; //change in y
private static ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 


public Arrows() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    requestFocus();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    //*********
    //here need to repaint according to the key
    //need to update to make so can press (and hold) multiple different keys at once
    //*********

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x, y , 20, 20);
    //for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++){ //********> only want to handle one at a time
        //handle the key

      //***Should move this to somewhere else, so repaint after update stuff in keyPressed

    //}
    //x += cx;
    //y += cy;
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(x + cx, y + cy, 20, 20);
}



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 
    //******
    //need to add to the keyList here
    //might want to use bitset
    //******
    //keys.add(e.getKeyCode());
    //**********************************
    //c = keys.get(0);
    c = e.getKeyCode();
        switch(c){
        case 37: 
            //left arrow 
            cx -= 3;
            //keys.remove(0);
            break;
        case 38:
            // up arrow
            cy -= 3;
            //keys.remove(0);
            break;
        case 39:
            //right arrow
            cx += 3;
            //keys.remove(0);
            break;
        case 40:
            //down arrow
            cy += 3;
            //keys.remove(0);
            break;
        }
        //**********************************
    repaint();
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 
    //****
    //here need to remove key fromt he list, and may want to fix teleportation..
    //****

    //set the change values to 0
    c1 = e.getKeyCode();
    switch(c1){
    case 37: 
        //left arrow 
        cx = 0;
        break;
    case 38:
        // up arrow
        cy = 0;
        break;
    case 39:
        //right arrow
        cx = 0;
        break;
    case 40:
        //down arrow
        cy = 0;
        break;
    }
    repaint();
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public static void main(String[] s) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().add(new Arrows());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

    //need to null out keys
    keys.add(65);

    //here want to update every time through constant time accoridng to the keypressed     and ereleased crap

    //repaint();
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some general programming comments:

1. Don't use requestFocus(). Read the API for that method and it will suggest the better method to use.
2. Don't use magic numbers. 37, 38, 39, 40 don't mean anything. Use the proper KeyEvent.vK... variable.

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the most useful tutorial yet I've seen on key bindings (unlike the others, it actually makes a little sense).